# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: white space not allowed

Tags: java, applet, illegalargumentexception

I am attempting to embed an applet on a webpage. I have exported the code as a compressed applet in IntelliJ. Now, when I try to run it, I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: white space not allowed
    at java.net.URLPermission.normalizeHeaders(URLPermission.java:401)
    at java.net.URLPermission.init(URLPermission.java:189)
    at java.net.URLPermission.<init>(URLPermission.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.URLtoSocketPermission(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1424)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1048)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:985)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2648)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$300(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$12.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2565)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$12.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2563)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2562)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1768)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1429)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:713)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1428)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Ignored exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: white space not allowed
```

I believe the error was caused by trying to get an image with the `getImage()` method in the `Applet` class. This is the code:

```
try {
    image = new ImageIcon(main.getImage(main.getCodeBase(), imageName + ".png"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For reference, here's the tag I'm using in the HTML:

`<applet archive="https://github.com/nrubin29/FreeFall-Applets/blob/master/Noah/Noah.war?raw=true" code="FreeFallMain"></applet>`

If you want to see the error for yourself, just go to http://nrubin29.github.io/FreeFall-Applets/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not use whitespaces?

Comment: Where are the whitespaces? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: In your ```getImage``` argument, do you have whitespaces in the file path and if so, can you change the file names?

Comment: Just ran `jar -tf` on the exported binary to list all files and no files have whitespace in them.

Comment: What about the string returned by your ```main.getCodeBase()``` function? And are you sure it is that exception that is causing the problem and not another?

Comment: `main.getCodeBase()` is defined by `JApplet` so I can't imagine that would be the cause. I'm not completely sure if this is the problem, but when I was using `ImageIO` to read the images, I got a different error. When I switched to this, I got this new error. A Google search didn't return anything.

Comment: Which method in your try-catch block is causing the exception? There are three calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, it looks like there's an open bug around this exact behavior:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042622?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

In essence, the bug is that it's a core bug in Java, and nothing you can do can fix it. So you'll have to wait for Java 8u40 (if the fix actually hits their target release).

Comment: We have the same problem; it may be triggered by having a signed applet (which they're all supposed to be these days).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (with the upgrade from java 1.7.0_67 to java 1.8.0_25) opening a page that redirects to a pdf document with code like this:

```
InputStream in = new URL(myUrl).openConnection().getInputStream();
```

I have found a possible (hopefully temporary) workaround for those who can't wait next january (or april?) for java 8u40:

```
try {
    InputStream in = new URL(myUrl).openConnection().getInputStream();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    in = sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.openConnectionCheckRedirects(new URL(myUrl).openConnection());
}
```

You can obviously add log and check if the open connection is istanceof HttpURLConnection.

I'm open to suggestions if you think what I've done is very wrong (consider I've stripped the non-essential parts).

Answer (score 1):

Running Windows 7 I had this issue with JRE 8u25, and also with 8u40. I rolled back to 7u71 and the uploader works fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of those calls (or your main call) is causing a URL to be loaded (looks like it's a jar file), then there's a redirect, and there's a space or tab in one of the response HTTP headers names. What happens if you host the applet jar/war on a local webserver rather than Github?